# How to install 'hidapi' on Windows with Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, hidapi

I downloaded the source code of the back-end from [https://github.com/libusb/hidapi](https://HIDAPI%20library%20for%20Windows,%20Linux,%20FreeBSD%20and%20macOS) (GitHub).

I used to install it under [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) following the instruction:

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
make install
```

I installed 'hid' using 'pip install hid', but once I try

```python
import hid
```

in Python I get:

```
raise ImportError(error)
ImportError: Unable to load any of the following libraries:libhidapi-hidraw.so libhidapi-hidraw.so.0 libhidapi-libusb.so libhidapi-libusb.so.0 libhidapi-iohidmanager.so libhidapi-iohidmanager.so.0 libhidapi.dylib hidapi.dll libhidapi-0.dll
```

Searching where Cygwin had installed, the library I found that in *C/cygwin64/usr/local/include/hidapi* was the header *hidapi.h* and in *C/cygwin64/usr/local/lib/libhidapi.a*, *libhidapi.dll.a*, *libhidapi.la* the objects.

I also tried to follow this answer, but it did not *work: [How to Determine where to install hidapi.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620247/how-to-determine-where-to-install-hidapi-dll)*