# Installing&&Importing pyhidapi and hidapi issues

Tags: python, installation, import, hid, hidapi

Here is the error pycharm is throwing:

```
ImportError: Unable to load any of the following libraries:libhidapi-hidraw.so libhidapi-hidraw.so.0 libhidapi-libusb.so libhidapi-libusb.so.0 
libhidapi-iohidmanager.so libhidapi-iohidmanager.so.0 libhidapi.dylib hidapi.dll libhidapi-0.dll
```

I've installed PYHIDAPI and HIDAPI through pip (pip install hid, pip install pyhidapi)and checked to see they were being installed to the python version being used by my API (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps). Still, when running the program, the line "import hid" throws the given error:

```
ImportError: Unable to load any of the following libraries:libhidapi-hidraw.so libhidapi-hidraw.so.0 libhidapi-libusb.so libhidapi-libusb.so.0 libhidapi-iohidmanager.so libhidapi-iohidmanager.so.0 libhidapi.dylib hidapi.dll libhidapi-0.dll.
```

I've checked stack overflow for a solution to this as well: [how to install hidapi on windows with cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753345/how-to-install-hidapi-on-windows-with-cygwin) has no solutions posted, but it links the following stack overflow with solutions: [How to Determine where to install hidapi.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620247/how-to-determine-where-to-install-hidapi-dll). I was not able to implement the solutions given because when I downloaded the repository, it did not contain a .dll or a .lib file to place in the System32 file. I was also not able to to implement the 2nd solution provided. For some reason, when I was trying to implement the 2nd solution, the system could not recognize that any of the file names existed.

Anwhoo, it would be preferable if I can solve this by Friday because that's when my internship ends. I will save the link to this post for the next person who needs to deal with this problem if I can't solve it by then.