# Can't load hidapi with Python library "hid" on Windows

Tags: python, windows, hidapi

sorry if the question is not well asked)

I'm trying to use the [Python library hid](https://pypi.org/project/hid/), which rely on the [hidapi library](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi). hid seems to not be able to load hidapi, as it's telling me here:

```sh
$ python
Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[...]\Python310\site-packages\hid\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    raise ImportError(error)
ImportError: Unable to load any of the following libraries:libhidapi-hidraw.so libhidapi-hidraw.so.0 libhidapi-libusb.so libhidapi-libusb.so.0 libhidapi-iohidmanager.so libhidapi-iohidmanager.so.0 libhidapi.dylib hidapi.dll libhidapi-0.dll
```

The problem is that I have downloaded one of those libraries from hidapi's release page (the Windows x64 version), but it doesn't seem to matter where I put it, it doesn't work. It is in my PATH:

```sh
$ echo $PATH
[...]:/c/Program Files/hidapi:[...]

$ ls -lh "/c/Program Files/hidapi"
total 3.0M
-rwxr-xr-x 1 [...] 197121  98K Jan 28 14:38 hidapi.dll*
-rw-r--r-- 1 [...] 197121 5.7K Jan 28 14:38 hidapi.lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 [...] 197121 2.9M Jan 28 14:38 hidapi.pdb
```

Even if I put it in the folder where I'm running Python from, or in System32, the same error happens again. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620247/how-to-determine-where-to-install-hidapi-dll) didn't worked either

**EDIT:** I didn't solve the core problem, but the ctypes library that is trying to load the library isn't skiping it because it can't find it but because it isn't a valid Win32 app (`[WinError 193] %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide` is the error, in french though). Maybe it is be cause it's not registered, but I'm not sucessful at trying to register it.

I've found a workaround: manually load the hidapi library before loading the hid library

```py
import ctypes
ctypes.CDLL('[my path to the DLL]\\hidapi.dll')
import hid
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Uninstall current hid module

```
pip uninstall hid
```

2. Install hidapi

```
pip install hidapi
```

3. Follow this steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi.git  
cd cython-hidapi  
git submodule update --init    
python setup.py build 
python setup.py install   
pip install -e .
```

4. It should be working. Run follow test script

```
python try.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I put `hidapi.dll` and `hidapi.lib` in `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310` and it worked ! :-)